# Node Winston log file forced string conversion

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

In a Node project, I want to show the contents of a Winston log file in a React interface. Reading the file:

```
let content;
fs.readFile("path", "utf-8", function read(err, data) {
  if (err)
      throw err;

 content = data; 
 });
```

I send them to the interface:

```
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(content));
});
```

And i get the content in a .jsx file:

```
getLogs().then(res => {
            let datafromfile = JSON.parse(res);
            // Use the data
            return;
        }).catch(err => {
            return err.response;
        });
```

The issue i am having is that `fs` converts all the data into a string (since i am putting the utf-8 encoding and do not want to be returned a buffer) and therefore i cannot manipulate the objects in the log file to show them structurally in the interface. Can anyone guide how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not debugged this, but a lot of this depends on whether or not the the Winston file your loading actually has JSON in it.

If it does then JSONStream is your friend and leaning through or through2 is helpful you in node (streams).

following, code/pseudo

```
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    const logPath = ‘somePath’; // maybe it comes from the req.query.path
    const parsePath = null; // or the token of where you want to attemp to start parsing
    fs.createReadStream(logPath)
      .pipe(JSONStream.parse(parsePath))
      .pipe(res);
});
```

- [JSONStream](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream)
- [fs.createReadStream](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-read-stream/) and [node docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options)
- [through2](https://github.com/rvagg/through2)

Comment: Thank you for the information. The Winston file has JSON in it. But i am struggling with some circular structures in the log files. Do any of these libraries have any way of ignoring the circularities? In the docs i did not find any useful information

Comment: Update: I changed the approach,and simply used `fs.createReadStream` and `readline` from the [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/readline.html). It worked.